# Proxy - Change clients webpage header

Tags: javascript, proxy

I've looked everywhere, and I can't find anything. Is there a way that I can run a proxy that will add my code to the webpages the clients browse under my proxy. (EX: `<title>My Proxy service</title>`)

This way I can use JavaScript and HTML to interact with the webpages elements.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But that's a pretty evil thing to do, and will cause all kinds of problems with web pages your clients try to use.

Comment: @GregHewgill is there any proxy server applications that let you chose what code is added?